# Need command to edit a service's log on to Local System Account

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, services, windows-services

When you right click a service in services.msc and go to properties and Log On, it lets you change it to Local System account, how can I switch to that setting with a batch command, I want to switch Telnet to use Local System Account.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use:

```
sc config "Service Name" obj= LocalSystem
```

> Note: You need to open command prompt as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Use the versatile SC command:

```
sc config "<ServiceName>" obj= "<AccountName>" password= "<Password>"
```

Note: the spaces after "obj=" and "password=" are required!

Comment: This sets the **Log On** property of _This account_ and not _Local System account_