# batch: configure a service to logon as a user with password

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-services

trying to configure `Service1` service on `windows 7 sp1` to logon as user `user1` with password `password1` using this batch script:

```
net user user1 /delete

net user user1 password1 /add 
net localgroup administrators user1 /add
wmic useraccount where "Name='user1'" set PasswordExpires=false

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList" /v user1 /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

net stop "Service1"
sc config "Service1" start= delayed-auto type= own obj= ".\user1" password= "password1"
net start "Service1"
```

fails with : `Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.`

but setting the user and password using the UI works without any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem was resolved by adding this line to the script

```
ntrights.exe +r SeServiceLogonRight -u user1
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\ntrights.exe` is installed from this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804140757/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17657)

Answer (score 4):

Given this looks authentication related, I would double-check things like format of your username schema, if there's a policy for "Deny Logon Service", and check the permissions for the user account that's trying to logon and start the service by watch of your batch file for starters.

[Adding some info for that 1069 error](https://www.codetwo.com/kb/troubleshooting-error-1069-the-service-did-not-start-due-to-a-logon-failure-for-sent-items-update/). There's [a good stackoverflow post that covers this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619112/how-do-i-fix-the-error1069-the-service-did-not-start-due-to-logon-failure).

It looks like there was a similar [post for this to edit a Windows service to log on as a specified user using a batch script](https://superuser.com/questions/467554/edit-windows-service-to-log-on-as-specific-user-using-a-batch-script) that may help get you where you need to be.

Based on the original answer, it's using `sc \\server config ServiceName obj= Domain\user password= pass` and looks like it should sort what you're trying to do, but I'd like to test this on my dev env as a sanity check as soon as I have some time and can chase back.

An [alternative could be](https://superuser.com/questions/915644/need-command-to-edit-a-services-log-on-to-local-system-account) using `sc config "Service Name" obj= LocalSystem`, which is similar to the above.

[Glancing through a different post](https://superuser.com/questions/747094/easiest-way-to-grant-log-on-as-a-service-to-a-windows-user-from-the-command-li), going with [ntrights](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html) could potentially be helpful too, depending on any unforeseen variables with the use case. `ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u username -m \\%COMPUTERNAME%`

If you're using [PowerShell and want to leverage that with an encrypted password](https://superuser.com/questions/879389/edit-windows-service-user-with-a-batch-script-and-encrypted-password), you could go that route, but the two previous examples seem close to what you're attempting to do.

**Update June 4, 2023:** The old Microsoft URL (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) detailing ntrights 404's as of now. Thank you for the heads-up comment Dennis! Replaced it with SS64's page as the next best means of continuity.

Comment: The ntrights link in this answer gives a 404 error.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up Dennis, I appreciate that. Been traveling, so I hadn't had time to address it, but it should now point to SS64's page detailing ntrights as a "next best thing" from a continuity perspective.